# How to get the authenticated user name under apache while in python code?

Tags: python, apache, apache2, cgi

Basically I just need to get the authenticated username from apache2, (for basic / similar authentication schemes) but while in python.

In php, this is simple, and looks like this:

```
$username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];`
```

Here is what the relevent section of the config in the site's sites-enabled config looks like:

```
#Provides Authentication for the admin pages
<Location /admin>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "example.com"
  AuthUserFile /data/passwd_admin
  Require valid-user
</Location>`
```

However, I cannot seem to find any method of retrieving this information from python.

Comment: is that just basic .htaccess authentication? how is the user authenticated?

Comment: @Joran Beasley Yes, though I'm not defining it in a .htaccess, it's in apache's site-specific sites-enabled config.  I'll edit my post with the relevant section added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, there doesn't appear to be an easy, clean way to directly get these headers from within python without using complex external libraries.

However, **assuming the python is running in a CGI-type context,** Apache will cram this information in environment variables for you to pull from, and this works wonderfully, and is incredibly easy:

```
import os
print os.environ["REMOTE_USER"]
```

Works to easily get the authenticated user, and this works not only for basic auth, but pretty much any authentication scheme used my Apache.

Comment: From memory that will not work with mod_python. If it is providing a value then something else is broken as that will fail in a multithreaded configuration. The correct way in mod_python is to access the 'user' attribute of the request object from memory. BTW, mod_python is pretty well dead and you shouldn't be using it for anything new.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks, You're right.  Turns out what I thought I was doing I wasn't actually doing.  The way my configuration is set up, I'm actually treating it as a CGI script, and not using mod_python.  I'm not sure why I thought I was using mod_python, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import request,Flask
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    auth = request.authorization
    if not auth:return "No Auth!"
    return auth.username+":"+auth.password

app.run(debug=True)
```

see : http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/